# CPU caching when multithreading behaviour

Tags: c#

Taking CPU caching and any possible compiler optimizations into account:

1. Is it possible for "False" to be written to the console?
2. Is option 1 setting up a memory fence that guarantees the freshness of the object reference and the field?
3. Is option 2 less "safe" than option 1 in any way?

   ```
   class Program
   {
       class Test
       {
           internal bool value = false;
       }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Test test = new Test();

           //Option 1
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => 
           {
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
               Console.WriteLine(((Test)s).value); 
           }, test);

           //Option 2
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) =>
           {
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
               Console.WriteLine(test.value);
           });

           test.value = true;
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, of course.  There is no synchronization to prevent either option #1 or option #2's worker threads from printing out the `false` value before the main thread sets it to `true`.  While the contrived example uses a Thread.Sleep to prevent it from ever realistically occurring, there is no **real** synchronization here.
2. No, option 1 is simply sending a reference to `s` to the thread pool for forwarding to the delegate.  Any memory fencing that happens should be considered an implementation detail, and as far as I am aware none occurs.  There is certainly nothing (other than the aforementioned `Thread.Sleep()`) preventing option #1's worker thread from printing "false" before the main thread sets it to true.
3. Option 2 is less safe in that you are closing over a variable which may be modified in a less contrived example.  See Eric Lippert's [blog post on the subject of closing over loop variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)- the same advice applies to option #2.

Answer (score 2):

There is no meaningful difference between 1 and 2 in terms of the specific scenario presented (where `test` is not reassigned). The real question is: "is the behaviour guaranteed?" To answer that properly, I would be looking at `lock`. You could use `volatile`, but that is very rarely understood properly - it will often work for the wrong reasons.

If in doubt, use something like a `lock`.

Answer (score 1):

The ThreadPool takes time to initialize before executing your workitem, so before it starts working on your other threads, it's already changed the value to true.  Adding some locking and a slight delay before changing the value to true, yields false in both cases.

```
class Program
{
    class Test
    {
        internal object lockValue = new Object();
        internal bool value = false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();

        //Option 1
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) =>
        {
            lock (test.lockValue)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(((Test)s).value);
            }
        }, test);

        //Option 2
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) =>
        {
            lock (test.lockValue)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(test.value);
            }
        });

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        lock (test.lockValue)
        {
            test.value = true;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This demonstrates that there is some time to starting up a thread, but the result that you get is just as coincidental as the original poster's code.  It just happens that starting a thread **on your machine** takes less than 100ms, and so the lock statements in option #1 and option #2 hit before the lock statement in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. if Test was a value type it might have mattered something, but as the code is written it doesn't.
2. passing a reference type , and using closure are almost identical, closure (in C#) just creates a little container class that gets passed to the function. the delegate is also handled a little differently, you can use a reflector to see exactly what happens.
3. what you have written is completely  undefined behavior, you can't know (C# wise) which thread will start first, or whether the setting line happen first.
4. avoid sharing memory between threads. you can copy data, you can use immutable, but you should avoid sharing mutable data. first and foremost for performance reasons by the way, copying is usually faster then syncing.
5. even if you share memory , unless you really know what you are doing, avoid relaying on memory barriers and other sorts of implicit synchronization, they behave differently on different platforms  (32, 64, IA64) and the semantics are very ... petty...

and read this:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/